# Access Android with USB Debug Interface

Tags: android

How can I access Android data with USB Debug Interface on Microsoft Windows? I'm interested in reading and writing contact data.

Comment: Are you basically looking for USB "sync" functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You want the adb tool I think - http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html . You can do things like `adb shell` to launch a shell into your phone. Also things like

`adb push file.txt /sdcard/file.txt`

The default contacts app allows you to export your contacts to USB storage. Something like /sdcard/0001.vcf. You can get that by doing

`adb pull /sdcard/0001.vcf path/to/local/0001.vcf`

Edited as per comments below (also because this wouldn't fit in the comments)

Well one option would be to write your own Android app, to access the contact information and write that out to the card, or even transfer it to your computer over WiFi or something (You would need a corresponding component on your computer for this).

The other option is to checkout [taskbomb](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.androidideas.taskbomb). The page also has links to ScriptLauncher. Also [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/). If you are familiar with any of the scripting languages it supports (Python, Ruby, Lua .. and some more) then you might be able to access contact information through there. SL4A is still evolving and not all the things that you can do through java have been exposed there, but its worth having a look. I'm still exploring it myself.

Comment: That is great, but how can I automate import/export of contacts?